# Dependency injection в ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dependency-injection

Сейчас сделано так

```
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserService service;
        private ApplicationContext _context;
        public UserController(ApplicationContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            service = new UserService(context);
        }
   ...
```

Хотел бы что бы было вот так (DI)

```
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserService service;
        private ApplicationContext _context;
        public UserController(ApplicationContext context, UserService service)
        {
            _context = context;
            this.service = service;
        }
   ...

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string connection = "Server=ms-sql-8.in-solve.ru;Database=1gb_city-move;user id=1gb_city-move;password=a4bea42fsg;";
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            // проинжектить userService примерно так
            services.AddSingleton<UserService, UserService>(); // как-то передать параметр - экземпляр ApplicationContext
```

Есть ли смысл так делать и правильно ли это? Если да, как мне получить доступ к экземпляру ApplicationContext?
В IServiceCollection его не нахожу

Спасибо

UPD

Сейчас сделал так:

```
 public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserService service;
        private ApplicationContext _context;
        public UserController(ApplicationContext context, UserService uSrv)
        {
            _context = context;
            service = uSrv;
        }
    ...
```

Но

```
public UserService(ApplicationContext context)
{
```

- конструктор с параметром

в Startup  я не инжектил. Сам контейнер проинжектил UserService контекстом?

Всё так?

Если да, то по аналогии я делаю:

```
   public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationContext _context;
        private readonly UserService userService;
        private readonly AuthService authService;
        public AccountController(ApplicationContext context, AuthService authService, UserService uSrv)
        {
            _context = context;
            userService = uSrv;
            this.authService = authService;
        }
```

и даже если я инжектю

```
services.AddSingleton<UserService, UserService>();
```

при запуске получаю ошибку

InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationContext' from singleton 'WebApplication1.BLL.UserService'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite scopedCallSite, CallSiteValidatorState state)

Comment: DI контейнер работает с интерфейсами. Создайте интерфейс на основе класса `UserService`, в конструктор передавайте интерфейс `public UserController(IApplicationContext context, IUserService service)`  и тогда можно будет `services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>()`.

Comment: как контекст передать?

Comment: Контейнер сам передаст

Answer (score 0):

> и даже если я инжектю
>
> ```
> services.AddSingleton<UserService, UserService>();
> ```
>
> при запуске получаю ошибку

Незнаю поможет ли но в єтом случае нужно делать так:

```
services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь создать singleton сервис,с зависимостью от scoped сервиса, то есть ApplicationContext создается на каждый запрос, а UserService только один раз, соответственно, вам просто нужно зарегистрировать UserService тоже как scoped сервис:

```
services.AddScoped<UserService>();
```

В остальном вы все делаете верно, все сервисы сами получат свои зависимости от контейнера.